# margin property not working with select element in css

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class= "foo">
<select >blablabl</select>;</br>
<select >blablabl</select>;
</div>
```

in css

```
.foo select{
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

The output is 2 select elements adjacent to each other and not seperated by 50px. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`select` elements are `display: inline` by default (generally) and will not respect margins.  Change them to `display: block` if you want each to be on its own line, or `display: inline-block` if you want each to have a large bottom margin.

EDIT: I see you have the `<br>`, so they will be on two separate lines with `display: inline-block` as well.

Comment: `select` are `display: inline-block` in Firefox at least and in [informative, not normative default stylesheet for HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) (but browsers are free to have the defaults they want, and that's what they do especially with form elements!)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class= "foo">
  <select >blablabl</select>
  <select >blablabl</select>
</div>
```

in css

```
.foo select {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class= "foo">
    <select ><option>blablabl</option></select>;</br>
    <select ><option>blablabl</option></select>;
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.foo select{
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```